# Replace each unique value in a pandas dataframe with a unique incremental string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is 4 columns wide and 6k rows. It looks something like

```
   itm cla1 cla2 num
0   77   99    1  0.7
1   45   71   21  0.9
2   27   15   99    3
3   67   21   15  .11
4   77   15   90    7
...
```

Within the dataset, I'd like to group every 'itm' that shares a value together and replace them with a unique incremental string.
I'd like to do the same for 'cla1' and 'cla2' except I'd like 'cla1' and 'cla2' to share unique incremental strings (that are not used in 'itm').

So a result that looks something like

```
   itm cla1 cla2 num
0   A0   X0  X98  0.7
1   A1   X1   X9  0.9
2   A2   X2   X0    3
3   A3   X3   X2  .11
4   A0   X5   X0    7
...
```

Any suggestions on how to put this together? Unfortunately just adding a string to the start of each value is not what I'm looking for. I'd like it to be incremental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.fromkeys` to generate unique values and retain their "seen" order.

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(df['itm'])
{77: None, 45: None, 27: None, 67: None}
```

Using `enumerate` you can build the mapping:

```
>>> { k: f"A{n}" for n, k in enumerate(dict.fromkeys(df['itm'])) }
{77: 'A0', 45: 'A1', 27: 'A2', 67: 'A3'}
```

You can `.stack()` the multi-columns to have them use the same mapping.

```
itm = { k: f"A{n}" for n, k in enumerate(dict.fromkeys(df['itm'])) }
cla = { k: f"X{n}" for n, k in enumerate(dict.fromkeys(df[['cla1', 'cla2']].stack())) }
```

You can then pass these to `.replace()`

```
>>> df['itm'].replace(itm)
0    A0
1    A1
2    A2
3    A3
4    A0
Name: itm, dtype: object
```

```
>>> df[['cla1', 'cla2']].replace(cla)
  cla1 cla2
0   X0   X1
1   X2   X3
2   X4   X0
3   X3   X4
4   X4   X5
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The other answers provided the necessary code, but I'm selecting this as the answer (for future users) since it provides solid explanations along with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the unique values then map it as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
a = [[77, 99, 1, 0.7],[45,   71, 21, 0.9],
   [27 ,  15,   99,    3],
   [67 ,  21,   15,  .11],
   [77  , 15,   90 ,   7]]
columns = ['itm', 'cla1', 'cla2', 'num']
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=columns)
itm_unique = set(df['itm'])
cla_unique = set(df['cla1']).union(set(df['cla2']))
d1 = {k: 'A'+str(idx) for idx, k in enumerate(itm_unique)}
d2 = {k: 'X'+str(idx) for idx, k in enumerate(cla_unique)}
df['itm'] = df.itm.map(d1)
df['cla1'] = df['cla1'].map(d2)
df['cla2'] = df['cla2'].map(d2)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the unique values in the `itm` and `cla1`,`cla2` columns as a series, then add your prefix to those series before merging back to the original dataframe and replacing the original column with the merged index:

```py
items = df['itm'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).add_prefix('A').reset_index()
clas = pd.concat([df['cla1'],df['cla2']]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).add_prefix('X').reset_index()
df = df.reset_index(names='idx') \
       .merge(items, on='itm').drop('itm', axis=1).rename(columns={'index':'itm'}) \
       .merge(clas, left_on='cla1', right_on=0).drop(['cla1', 0], axis=1).rename(columns={'index':'cla1'}) \
       .merge(clas, left_on='cla2', right_on=0).drop(['cla2', 0], axis=1).rename(columns={'index':'cla2'}) \
       .set_index('idx').sort_index()
```

Output:

```
      num itm cla1 cla2
idx
0    0.70  A0   X0   X4
1    0.90  A1   X1   X3
2    3.00  A2   X2   X0
3    0.11  A3   X3   X2
4    7.00  A0   X2   X5
```